# Meteorjs: Remove reactivity to a certain publish statement

Tags: meteor, publish, subscribe

Is there any way to publish once the subscribe request is made and then stop pushing the changes that are made to the collection until the client subscribes again?

I have this scenario:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function () {
    return Messages.find(); //Do not push changes to this collection!
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("posts");
```

Comment: When you say "autopublish", you seem to not refer to the package but the reactivity and data synchronization. Am I correct?

Comment: @Kyll yes sorry for my bad explanation. Yes I want the data to NOT be REACTIVE.

Comment: I'm ready to answer, just a quick question: Would a method do the trick? Sending an array of all posts to the client?

Comment: @Kyll Well if I have to do the trick I will but I don't want to manually render the blaze template. What I rally want is this publish statement not to reactively update the client and neither to terminate the publish function (I think if I terminate the function I will add waiting time to the user till it will be re-initiated if I'm not wrong).

Comment: The template could be rendered all the same with an array of data rather than a cursor? If you want some more informations on this, we will need to see it.

Comment: I don't really understand can you be more specific and explain it to me what you are suggesting. Sorry for the nobitity.

Answer (score 3):

If you just have to do a one-shot data send to the client, using a method may work:

```
//Server
Meteor.methods({
  getSomePosts : function(limit)
  {
    check(limit, Number);
    return Posts.find({}, {limit : limit}).fetch();
  }
});

//Client
Meteor.call('getAllPosts', function(err, result) {
  //Do stuff with the result
});
```

Note that this will be heavy on your database, you may want to use a variable and update it periodically rather than fetching the whole collection each time a client calls the method.

[More about limits in the doc!](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)

Comment: Thank you for the method example. And thank you for the suggestion that I should not transmit all the post, I did that example to not be complex. Is there any way to limit the Meteor.publish() to just return the cursor when the Meteor.subscribe() calls the publish, just to remove the reactivity ? (If no I will go the method way)

Comment: Sure, let me edit my answer, you can use a limit with a cursor.

Comment: Well thank you for the mongo query, I know I can add what I want to the query. Any answer how can I remove the reactivity in the Meteor.publish() except the Meteor.methods() way.

Comment: You'd have to tweak the Collection declaration and the publication in pretty ugly ways. Check Meteor.Collection in the doc.